# Show that exists $x \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $x^3+x=3$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that exists $x \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $x^3+x=3$

I did:

I take $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R} \mid x^3+x<3\}$

So, this set is bounded and by completeness of the real numbers exists $a=\sup(S)$

Then I want to prove that $a^3+a=3$

And then in order to get a contradiction I suppose that $a^3+a>3$

and how $a $ is the supremum then $\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R} $ exists $b \in S$ such that
$a-\epsilon<b$ then $(a-\epsilon)^3+b<b^3+b<3$

But I'm stuck from here. I'm not able to use derivatives, or continuity so I can't use IVT

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1:

Apply the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) (which does *not* require taking derivatives) to the continuous function $f(x)=x^3+x-3$ on some closed interval.

Hint 2:

For the function defined above, $f(-1)<0$ and $f(2)>0$.

---

I don't understand what you mean by "I'm not able to use derivates or continuity". If you wish, you can unwrap the proof of the intermediate value theorem and apply the steps to the function $f$ above.

Alternatively, you may use the fundamental theorem of algebra and the fact that all complex roots come up as conjugate pairs. (Well, you only have the `real-analysis` tag...)

Comment: I think this is an excellent example for the use of the intermediate theorem in a proof.

Comment: The OP says explicitly that continuity and IVT are not allowed. Presumably the professor wants the students to apply the *proof* of the IVT in this concrete case.

Comment: What the OP very likely means is the fact that any course in Real Analysis starts with the properties of real numbers and supremum/infimum, and maybe the Dedeking cuts construction of the real numbers. This is done way before speaking of continuity and derivatives, and this is a standard exercise about the supremum at that point.

Comment: @TedShifrin: You may be right; I read "I'm not able to use derivatives, or continuity so I can't use IVT" differently, it is possible that OP does not know how to use IVT.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
If
$$a^3+a >3$$
and
$$0< \epsilon < \min \{ 1, \frac{a^3+a -3}{3a^2+3a+2} \}$$

[ I figured out the value by finding first the upperbound $3a^2\epsilon-3a\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3+\epsilon <3a^2\epsilon+3a\epsilon+2\epsilon$ below and then solving $3a^2\epsilon+3a\epsilon+2\epsilon< a^3+a-3$. I like to point out to my students that in many proofs in real Analysis you do the computations first to figure out the inequalities you need, but write the proof in reverse order]

Then
$$
3a^2\epsilon-3a\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3+\epsilon <3a^2\epsilon+3a\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3+\epsilon <3a^2\epsilon+3a\epsilon+2\epsilon< a^3+a -3
$$
This gives
$$(a-\epsilon)^3+a-\epsilon=a^3+a-3a^2\epsilon+3a\epsilon^2-\epsilon^3-\epsilon>3$$

Now, use the fact that there exists some $b \in S$ such that $b >a-\epsilon$. But this leads to the contradiction
$$
3< (a-\epsilon)^3+a-\epsilon \leq b^3+3 \leq 3
$$

Comment: I guess part of this deduction is how IVT is proved.

Comment: @ZiqiFan For IVT the argument can be made easier by continuity: If $f(a)<0$ and $f(b) >0$ and we denote by $c$ the supremum of $\{ x : f(x) <0 \}$ the definition of the supremum combined with continuity gives immediately that $f(x) \leq 0$. Next $f >0$ for $x >c$ combined with continuity gives that $f(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: @ZiqiFan The computation above is actually the $\epsilon -\delta$ proof of continuity for $x^3+x$, in an implicit way. If you replace $a^3+a-3$ by $\epsilon$ and $\frac{a^3+a -3}{3a^2+3a+2}$ by $\delta$ you get the proof of continuity (from the left) at $x=a$.

Comment: Thank you! just one question from where does the 1 come from in $0< \epsilon < \min \{ 1, \frac{a^3+a -3}{3a^2+3a+2} \}$

Comment: @AraceliChavez The $\epsilon^2$ and $\epsilon^3$ terms you get in the expression make the computations tricky. A stardard trick is to restrict to $\epsilon <1$ and then use $\epsilon^2 <\epsilon$ and $\epsilon^3<\epsilon$. This way I transformed the cubic $3a^2\epsilon+3a\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3+\epsilon$ into a linear function in $\epsilon$, making the last inequality easy to solve.

Comment: @AraceliChavez Since you need $\epsilon <1$  to make this trick work and $\epsilon <\frac{a^3+a -3}{3a^2+3a+2}$ to make the last inequality work, you can make both inequalities true by making $\epsilon <$ minimum. This is standard in analysis and you'll get used to this soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use the IVT or continuity, then the simplest method in my mind is to explicitly solve the polynomial equation. It is difficult to show that the following **real** number

$$x= \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{18}(27+\sqrt{741})}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3(27+\sqrt{741})}}$$

is a solution to the equation $x^3+x-3=0$ (at least by hand). However, it is possible (again, not as easy as using the IVT) and suffices as a direct proof of the original claim.

Comment: this assumes we know that $\sqrt[3]{b}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ always  exist for $b > 0$.  Which maybe has been proven in the OPs text but I doubt it.

Comment: Seriously? ....

Comment: Yes. OP wanted a proof that there exists $x$ with that property. Without using the IVT, a direct computation is the easiest and least painful way of proving that such an $x$ exists (at least in my mind).

Answer (score 0):

$S = \{x| x^3 + x < 3\}$ is one set but $T= \{x|x^3 + x < 3\}$ is another.

If $s = \sup S$ and $t = \inf T$ it's easy to prove $\sup S \le \sup T$.

Now if you can prove $s^3 + s \ge 3$ then you can *probably* use a similar argument to prove $t^3 + t \le 3$.

That means $t^3 + t \le s^3 + s$.  It's easy to prove $x^3 + x$ is increasing so $t^3 + t \le s^3 + s\iff t\le s$.

so you have $t \le s$ and $s \le t$ and $t^3 +t \le 3 \le s^3 +s$ which altogether shows $s=t=3$.

so what argument can we use to prove that $s^3 + s \ge 3$?

Consider that if $u > s$ then $u \not \in S$ so $u^3 + u \ge 3$. If we assume $s^3 +s < 3$, the would mean for all $\epsilon > 0$ then $(s+\epsilon)^3 + (s+\epsilon) \ge 3$

If we can show there is an $\epsilon > 0$ so that $(s+\epsilon)^3 + (s + \epsilon) < 3$ that would be a contradiction and that would prove $s =\sup S \ge 3$.

Let's find such an epsilon we *need*

$(s+\epsilon)^3 + (s + \epsilon) < 3$

$s^3 + 3s^2\epsilon + 3s\epsilon^2 + \epsilon^3+s + \epsilon <3$.

$(3s^2+1)\epsilon + 3s\epsilon^2 + \epsilon^3 < 3 - (s^3 + s)$

Now we know if $s \ge 2$ then $s^3 + s \ge 10$ so $s< 2$ and if $\epsilon < 1$ we have:

$(3s^2+1)\epsilon + 3s\epsilon^2 + \epsilon^3 <13\epsilon + 6\epsilon + \epsilon =20 \epsilon$

So if we can find and $\epsilon < 1$ so that $20\epsilon < 3-(s^3 + s)$ we'd be done.

So as we are assuming $3-(x^3 + s) > 0$ we can just let $\epsilon < \min(1, \frac {3-(x^3 + s)}{20}$.

And we are done.  That's a a contradiction so $s^3 + s \ge 3$.